# why does variable not change in function

Tags: python

im using python 3.10.2
i wanted to make a program that cycled thru red green and blue values but the variable is not changing allthough i made variables global before the for loop

i wrote this

```
r,g,b=255,0,0
def c(c,v):
    global r,g,b
    for _ in range(255):
        exec(f'{c}-=1')
        exec(f'{v}+=1')
        print(r,g,b)
c('r','g')
c('g','b')
c('b','r')
```

it prints this

```
255 0 0
255 0 0
255 0 0
255 0 0
255 0 0
255 0 0
...
```

(many more times than this)

i expected it to print this

```
255 0 0
254 1 0
253 2 0
252 3 0
251 4 0
250 5 0
...
```

what do i need to do
(sorry for bad english)

Comment: Why do you need to such thing ?

Comment: Is this just a toy program to play with `exec`? In this case, you should read its documentation about the scope it uses. If this is for a real use, you should use a dict with `'r', 'g', 'b'` as keys, or some object that encapsulates them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the global keyword declaration is not read by the exec function.

I think I got the wanted result doing this

(Also you could have a much simpler solution without using `exec` but I guess you have your reasons :) )

```py
r, g, b = 255, 0, 0


def c(c, v):
    for _ in range(255):
        exec(f'global {c} ; {c}-=1')
        exec(f'global {v}; {v}+=1')
        print(r, g, b)


c('r', 'g')
c('g', 'b')
c('b', 'r')
```

Comment: But please don't use this in real code... See my comment under the question. Also, note that `exec` takes a `globals` parameter that is more suited to such things.

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem is that you are passing string values inside a f-string. But 'r', 'g' and 'b' are already strings.
Try to do

```
r,g,b=255,0,0
def c(c,v):
    global r,g,b
    for _ in range(255):
        exec(c + '-=1')
        exec(v + '+=1')
        print(r,g,b)
c('r','g')
c('g','b')
c('b','r')
```

Comment: That does not have any impact. The resulting string is exactly the same